# Arcpy array TypeError: Abstract Class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, array

I am using arc 10.2. Every time I add an array both python 2.7 and as a tool in Arc I am getting a "TypeError: Abstract Class". I have also tried changing my script multiple times to make the array differently but every time I call on the arcpy.Array() I get this error.

I have run the script on other computers with Arc and it works perfectly so I can't see an error with the script.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ArcGIS. I tried reverting back to 10.1 and 10.0 and I still get the same error.

Comment: It would be better to post a codes snippet whereas troubleshooting gets cleared.

Comment: I have multiple scripts working perfectly on other computers; however my computer they just don't work. So I don't think its an error in the code

Comment: Please include a code snippet. Personally, if one machine behaves differently to others I would uninstall ArcGIS for Desktop, remove all traces of Python, and then let the reinstall of ArcGIS for Desktop take care of installing Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I uninstalled all ArcGIS components and deleted all traces of Python and ArcGIS. Then installed ArcGIS and let it install components of Python again. Now the scripts work.

Maybe there was a problem when I first installed ArcGIS with the Python components.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to fix it, but before Python 2.6.x there was no explicit way to declare an abstract class. It changed with the abc (Abstract Base Class) module now available from the standard library in Python 2.7. I'm getting the same error with this line of code.

```
partGeom = arcpy.Geometry("polygon", arcpy.Array(trPoints))
```

The variable partGeom probably needs to be declared now...